# How to make a button come out of another button

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, angular-ng-if

I'm using Angular 5, and I wanted to press another button to get another button.

I do not know if I would have to use the `ngIf`, but I do not know how to identify the previous button.

example.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.heroes.push(hero);
      });
  }

  delete(hero: Hero): void {
    this.heroes = this.heroes.filter(h => h !== hero);
    this.heroService.deleteHero(hero).subscribe();
  }

}
```

example.html

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </a>
    <button class="delete" title="delete hero" (click)="delete(hero)">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide some kind of code or be more specific?

Comment: Its really not clear what you need. Please give more details.

Comment: When you say "*press another button to get another button*", I assume you want to change the text that is displayed on the button? Or did you want to actually have the button 'protrude' out of the button so that part of the original button is visible?

Comment: I want another button to appear.
As to confirm the action of pressing the button and it has to be a new <button>

Answer (score 0):

In your component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
  showSecondButton: boolean = false;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  delete(hero: Hero): void {
    this.heroes = this.heroes.filter(h => h !== hero);
    this.heroService.deleteHero(hero).subscribe();
    this.showSecondButton = true;
  }

}
```

In your html:

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </a>
    <button class="delete" title="delete hero" (click)="delete(hero)">x</button>
    <button *ngIf="showSecondButton"> Your second button</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

so your best bet is to create two buttons within a div, then have a toggle that switches the button that is displayed.

Example:

```
<div>
<button *ngIf=!displaysecondbutton (click)='showsecondbutton()'>First Button Yo</button>
<button *ngIf=displaysecondbutton>SecondButtonYo</button>

</div>

typescript file;

displaysecondbutton = false;
showsecondbutton(){
this.displaysecondbutton = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the code concise I would implement an if statement in your delete function:

```
public deleteConfirmed = false;
public confirmDelete = false;
delete(hero: Hero): void {
  if (deleteConfirmed) {
    confirmDelete = deleteConfirmed = false;
    this.heroes = this.heroes.filter(h => h !== hero);
    this.heroService.deleteHero(hero).subscribe();
  }
  else{
    confirmDelete = true;
  }
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<button class="delete" title="delete hero" (click)="delete(hero)">Delete</button>
<button *ngIf="confirmDelete" class="delete" title="delete hero" (click)="deleteConfirmed=true; delete(hero)">Confirm Deletion</button>
```

This way, you are always cycling the same function and just altering some states along the way.